# Why does subsitituting $-\beta(z-z_s)^2f''(z_s)=\xi^2$ yield $dz=\frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{-\beta f''(z_s)}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Background: This is from Balanis Electromagnetics 2nd pg.1000 describing the method of steepest descent. The author shows that the harmonic function U(x,y) changes most rapidly along a path s where its conjugate(V(x,y)) is constant by taking the derivative of $\frac{\partial U}{\partial s}$ with respect to an angle $\gamma$ swept around like a radar. At a saddle point $z_s$(a min max point for U) The taylor series for $f(z)\approx f(z_s)+1/2(z-z_s)^2f''(z_s)$
In the integral for the S.D.P a substitution is made that I don't understand:

$$-\beta(z-z_s)^2f''(z_s)=\xi^2$$

simplifies to

$$dz=\frac{d\xi}{\sqrt{-\beta f''(z_s)}}$$

instead of $$dz=\frac{\xi}{-\beta(z-z_s)f''(z_s)}d\xi$$

> Why?

Comment: Replace $\xi$ in the RHS of "your" formula by its value $\xi=\sqrt{-\beta(z-z_s)^2f''(z_s)}$... and rejoice.

Comment: Aha! It didn't even use the truncated Taylor series(f'=0).